# jQuery contents() causing problems in IE

Tags: jquery, text

I'm using the contents() function in jQuery in order to obtain some text within a LI which I can't target directly with a span or other selector.

The code I've written is as follows:

```
$('#tierArray_' + tierId).contents().each(function(i, node) {
  if (node.nodeName == "#text") {
    node.textContent = name;
  }
});
```

This works fine in Firefox and changes the target text to what is set in 'name'. In IE however I get the following errors:

"Object doesn't support this property or method"

This seems to relate to the line "node.textContent = name" as when I comment this out the error disappears.

In a nutshell I'm simply trying to replace some text with newly created text, the HTML markup is as follows:

```
<li class="ui-state-default" id="tierArray_105">
  <span style="display: block;" id="revoke_105">
    <a class="tierStatus" title="Revoke" href="#">Revoke</a> | 
    <a class="tierEdit" id="edit_tier_105" title="Bla 3aaa11" href="#">Edit</a>
  </span>
  <span style="display: none;" id="active_105">
    <a class="tierStatus" title="Activate" href="#">Activate</a> | 
    <a class="tierEdit" id="edit_tier_105" title="Bla 3aaa11" href="#">Edit</a>
  </span>
  Bla 3aaa11
</li>
```

So the text after the last span (Bla 4aaa11) will need to be replaced with some newly generated text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer does not support the [textContent](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_textcontent.asp) property.

However, since you only want to replace the contents of a text node, you should be able to use [nodeValue](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_document_nodevalue.asp) instead:

```
$("#tierArray_" + tierId).contents().each(function(i, node) {
    if (node.nodeName == "#text") {
        node.nodeValue = name;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the `.textContent` isn't supported by IE.  You may have luck setting the `.innerText` in IE instead:

```
if(typeof(node.textContent) != 'undefined'){
  node.textContent = name;
} else {
  node.innerText = name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `data` or `nodeValue` instead:

```
node.data = name;
node.nodeValue = name;
```

Both are widely supported across browsers:

[Quirksmode: nodeValue](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t22)

[Quirksmode: data](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t101)